# JS: Chrome extension setting cookies

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm using a Chrome extension to help me work on a webpage but it's setting cookies from doubleclick.net even though I've disabled third party cookies in the Chrome settings. It's annoying because they're filling up my console with messages.

They're not appearing in `document.cookie` so is there any way to delete them in JavaScript? Or some other way to stop them being set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally the use [EditThisCookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg?hl=en) extension for chrome when developing web apps using cookies. It allows creation, editing, deleting and most importantly for you blocking of cookies.

You can block a domain from setting a cookie by:

**1.** Select the cookie from the menu and click block.

[image]

**2.** This opens a menu where you can set a rule blocking the domain from creating new cookies.

[image]